Justify content not works properly
I want  to vertically center the register form regardless of screen size. But it does not works properly. Please help to fix this issue.
   import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Button, View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
    
    const RegisterScreen = () => {
      const [person1, setPerson1] = useState("");
      const [person2, setPerson2] = useState("");
    
      const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log("Person 1:", person1);
        console.log("Person 2:", person2);
        // Additional logic can be added here, such as form submission or validation
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Register Screen</Text>
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Person 1"
              onChangeText={setPerson1}
              style={styles.textInput}
            />
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Person 2"
              onChangeText={setPerson2}
              style={styles.textInput}
            />
            <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit} />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        marginBottom: 16,
      },
      formContainer: {
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent:"center"
      },
      textInput: {
        width: "100%"
      
      },
    });

I want  to vertically center the register form regardless of screen size. But it does not works properly. Please help to fix this issue

It's hard to fix code you haven't shown - also, it sounds like a CSS issue, yet your only tag is javascript. Perhaps that's the issue, you don't know what "language" to use to achieve your goal

The properties justifyContent and alignItems only work in flex (or grid) containers. It looks like you're trying to make the div with the container class a flex container, using flex: 1. The actual property to do this is display:
      container: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
      },

W3 Schools has a great tutorial for using CSS flexbox: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
